# Javascript "for" loop isnt fully executed on the first time

Tags: javascript

I am developing a calendar function for displaying Database Table Data in our CMS.

I generate a Calendar Table in JS. The database entries get generated in C# and get put in an array. The End Result looks like this:

```
var Termine = new Array(4);
Termine[0] = {
    ID:1,
    Datum:1442912403000,
    Titel:"Test",
    Detail:"Some encoded HTML"
};
Termine[1] = {
    ID:2,
    Datum:1444306500000,
    Titel:"Testing a bit more",
    Detail:"Some encoded HTML"
};
Termine[2] = {
    ID:3,
    Datum:1442880000000,
    Titel:"Test 2",
    Detail:"Some encoded HTML"
};
Termine[3] = {
    ID:4,
    Datum:1442932140000,
    Titel:"Test 3",
    Detail:"Some encoded HTML"
};
```

Now I am looping through this Array in a function and add the appointments (divs) to the Table:

```
function addTermine() {
    for (var i = 0; i < Termine.length; i++) {
        var t = Termine[i];
        var d = new Date(t.Datum);
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000);
        if (d.getFullYear() === currentYear && d.getMonth() === currentMonthInt-1) {
            var ID = d.getFullYear() + "-" + d.getMonth() + "-" + d.getDate();
            var longID =  d.getFullYear() + "-" + d.getMonth() + "-" + d.getDate() + "-" + d.getHours() + "-" + d.getMinutes();
            var hour = d.getHours();
            if (hour < 10) hour = "0" + hour;
            var min = d.getMinutes();
            if (min < 10) min = "0" + min;
            var s = "<div id=\"ter" + longID + "\" class=\"termin\" onmouseover=\"showDetail(event,'detail" + longID + "');\" onmouseout=\"hideDetail('detail" + longID + "');\">" + hour + ":" + min + "<br>" + t.Titel + "</div>";
            $("#cont" + ID).html($("#cont" + ID).html() + s);
            $("#ter" + longID).click(function () {
                location.href = window.location.href + "?cid=" + cid + "&col=" + t.ID + "&details=1";
            });
            var detail = "<div id=\"detail" + longID + "\" class=\"hoverDetail\">" + unescape(t.Detail) + "</div>";
            $("body").append(detail);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when this function is executed the first time (from `document.ready`) the for loop is only executed one time even tho `Termine.length` is 4 in the Debugger. When I execute the function after changing months to load that months appointments it executes correctly.

If anyone could point me towards why it doesnt execute correctly on the first try I'd be grateful.

I am testing this on our dev website feel free to debug it.

Comment: How do you know it isn't fully executed?  Maybe your conditions weren't met?

Comment: Could have something to do with the javascript error that occurs after displaying the first div `$.validator is undefined`

Comment: @Greg When I debugged the code and had a breakpoint on the first line of the for loop it only stopped once then exited the loop.
@Jamiec In what browser are you testing it? I use the current Google Chrome and dont get that error message. Tho I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'messages' of undefined`

Comment: @fluegu - yes in this case FF gave a more meaningful error message, however the message Chrome gives points to the same problem if you look at the bad line of code (`$.validator` is the "undefined" and it does not have property `messages`)

Comment: @fluegu I assumed you had an error, but you didn't include it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first calendar element adds to the dom a `<script>` element with the url `/xtend/javascript/messages_de.js`. When this script is loaded by the browser it causes a javascript error

> $.validator is undefined

This javascript error causes further javascript processing to halt. There is a race condition there also, sometimes the javascript continues before that bad script is loaded and in this case you get 4 new div's on the calendar.

The error occurs because the newly injected javascript code is attempting to use the jQuery [validate plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/), which you've not included.

Comment: Thank you very much. That error message didnt get to my console somehow. Added the JQueryValidate and now it works